# Cascading groupby Example

Tags: java, hadoop, distributed, cascading

I recently had to do a cascading job. I'm never had experience with distributed systems before, so I'm having some trouble understanding how to make this work.

I have a config file which has a bunch of buckets:

```
Bucket{
  bucket_name: "X"
  input_path: "s3://..."
  key_column: 1
  value_column: 2
  multivalue: false
  default_value: 
  type_column: int
} 
...
```

Basically, all I have to do is use this to collect a bunch of files (each of them is like a tsv table which maps url keys to some value) and then group by url's.

So basically, this is how the outline looks:

```
A --> |group |
B --> |by    |--> output 
C --> |url   |
```

I was wondering if the following logic is right:
1) I need to create a tap for each of the buckets i.e.

```
Tap inputTap = new GlobHfs(new TextLine(), bucket.getInputPath());
```

2) I need to create a EACH Pipe out of all the pipes (this part I am unsure about, do I need an each pipe, what should my filter/function be?). Right now, I have created an Each Pipe that splits the lines by tabs.

```
RegexSplitGenerator splitter = new RegexSplitGenerator("\t");
Pipe tokenizedPipe = bucket.getBucketName(), new Field("Line"), splitter));
```

3) Create a groupby Pipe that combines all of these Tokenized Pipes together.  I'm not precisely sure how to force the groupby pipe to select only the key columns, but the technique I'm using right now is:

```
Pipe finalPipe = new Groupby("Output Pipe", inputPipes, groupFields);
```

So is this the correct logic to approach this problem? Or are some of my steps redundant or incorrect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your thought looks good to me. Step 2 can be skipped if you split records when the tap is reading input files.

```
Tap inputTap = new Hfs(new TextDelimited("\t"), inputPath);
```

[Cascading for the Impatient](http://docs.cascading.org/impatient/) covers how to implement what you want to achieve, it's worthy to take a look at it.